# nginx + php-fpm produces 300ms overhead

Tags: php, nginx

I have currently setup a server to host a WordPress site, a single server that runs all nginx, php-fpm, WordPress and MariaDB. The site is heavily customized in the theme. While I am optimizing the site, I started off at WP level and got some success, Debug Bar reports PHP loading time down from ~700ms to ~300ms, however in Developer Console the PHP took ~600ms to complete loading (server ping <20ms). That means nginx and php-fpm and making ~250ms overhead.

To isolate the problem I used microtime() in index.php and confirmed the whole WP PHP took <350ms.

Then to attempt to solve, I have tried these settings:

- Using HTTP and disable GZIP
- `fastcgi_buffering off`
- Turn off access log
- Enable `tcp_nopush` and `tcp_nodelay`

However improvements are not significant. I want to know is it possible to get rid of the ~250ms overhead? As it seemed to me that 250ms on a high perf software like nginx is unreasonable and should be able to be eliminated. Any clue and help is appreciated.

PS: This is the first time asking on SO, sorry if I am not following the convention and rules.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, it was the [Autoptimize plugin to blame](https://serverfault.com/questions/906526/slow-ttfb-in-a-single-wordpress-site-in-a-nginx-environment-on-digitalocean-20). In short, Autoptimize performs ob_start at the beginning and starts buffering the whole HTML output, when all scripts ends (i.e. index.php exits), some of Autoptimize's code will then be executed and the minification occurs, before anything is sent to nginx. As a result:

1. Even using microtime() in index.php cannot time the whole processing correctly, because the minification starts *after* index.php ends.
2. Since it buffers the whole output, first byte cannot be sent before the minification completes.

We have done benchmark on various configuration on Autoptimize, and the result basically recommends removing it, i.e. enabling any of HTML/CSS/JS minifcation degrades the performance / increases TTFB severely.

## Benchmark

### All CSS JS HTML on

```
TTFB                 513
Overall_Elapsed      593
Body Size            464598
Req Count            144-154
```

### HTML Off, JS CSS On

```
TTFB                 318
Overall_Elapsed      380
Body Size            518211
Req Count            144-155
```

### HTML On, JS CSS Off

```
TTFB                 478.5
Overall_Elapsed      519
Body Size            285995
Req Count            161-165
```

### HTML JS CSS Off

```
TTFB                 75.8
Overall_Elapsed      373
Body Size            340439
Req Count            163-172
```

### Disable Autoptimize in WP

```
TTFB                 78.9
Overall_Elapsed      376
Body Size            339917
Req Count            163-171
```

- Req fluctuates due to ads network.

## Conclusion

In our theme we have 12 JS and 1 CSS, along with some other plugin's JS and CSS. Since we can easily merge the 12 JS into a single JS, as a result of the 19 reduced requests, we can reduce 11 of them by ourselves.

Furthermore, Autoptimize "save" the CSS request by inlining the entire style.css into `<head>` this largely bloats the HTML.

Therefore, I strongly advice you to *try* disabling Autoptimize and see if your site speed actually improves by that.